# Ignore everything but text when comparing files with diff?

Tags: diff

For the command `diff`, for file comparison, which options are required to for a file comparison where only the text is compared?

What I mean is I want to ignore all spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.

I've been trying different options but have not been able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: diff works by comparing lines, so I doubt you can meaningfully ignore newlines. There's also `wdiff`, which compares words, but again, whitespace-separated words.

Answer (score 2):

You can preprocess the files and then compare the stream. E.g. use `tr` to delete all spaces and newlines.

```
diff <( tr -d ' \n' <file1 ) <( tr -d ' \n' <file2)
```

Example files are `a` and `b` that share text but not space and newline positions:

```
cat a
1
2
3

cat b
1 2 3

diff -sq a b
Files a and b differ

diff -sq <( tr -d ' \n' <a ) <( tr -d ' \n' <b )
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

Note that

1. This will not differ between `these words` and `th esew ord s`
2. You have to pay good attention to what characters you are deleting
3. `diff`'s output file names are stream names and not file names

See `man tr` for special characters like tabs etc. (maybe the `[:space:]` set matches your needs best)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to in general just ignore all white-space (tabs, spaces: `-w`), and blank newlines (`-B`), then (assuming GNU diff):

```
$ diff -B -w file1 file2
```

Or, using the long option (see `man diff`),

```
$ diff --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-all-space file1 file2
```

This is basically the same (but more descriptive output) as pre-processing the file, e.g, with `tr`:

```
$ diff <(tr -d '[:space:]' < file1)  <(tr -d '[:space:]' < file2)
```

Comment: This still shows a difference for e.g. newline / absence thereof before an opening bracket (Allman vs 1TBS bracing style for C and brethren).

Comment: whoops: added missing option to ignore blank lines (`-B` / `--ignore-blank-lines`); still, if chars are on actual different lines, the files will still show as different via `diff`, in which case, use `tr` to strip out all whitespace

Comment: Won't the result be very hard to read? I'm thinking about using a code beautifier (like uncrustify) to homogenize the format before diffing.

Comment: that would probably be the way to go — and why code formatters are sometimes used as pre-commit hooks in version control (and just as controversial as "spaces vs tabs", which is probably the source of the question)

Comment: More controversial than that: Allman vs 1TBS!